# Can I add controls to PlaceHolder control in a sequence in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In ASP.NET WebForms (v 3.5), I have created a `PlaceHolder` control dynamically and added  `Label`, `literal`, and `TreeView` controls in a loop. If I run the application and the loop executes two times, I have found that two `Label`s and two `literal`s are displayed first and then two `TreeView` controls appeared. However, I want to display the controls in the order - `Label`, `literal`, `TreeView`, and ....

To solve this problem, I tried  `ControlPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add()` and `ControlPlaceHolder1.Controls.AddAt()` functions. None of these can display the controls in the order I want.

Is there any way I can solve this one?

Comment: Could you share your looping code?

Comment: @ScottE , I declared the TreeView control outside the loop. That's why it was not working. Once I declared the TreeView control inside the loop, it worked fine. You question helped me. Thanks.